# Rspec's it block text is not getting printed on terminal

Tags: rspec, watir-webdriver, rspec2

I have a test project in which I have multiple IT blocks. Every thing is going good but, while I run my rspec tests I am not getting the text inside my it blocks on the terminal. Instead I am getting just getting green dots on the terminal

[image: This is the terminal with 3 green dots]

Can anyone suggest how to get it blocks text on my terminal?

Here is the rspec gems version.

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rspec (3.3.0)
rspec-core (3.3.1)
rspec-expectations (3.3.0)
rspec-mocks (3.3.1)
rspec-support (3.3.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run `rspec --format=documentation` or just `rspec -fd` for brevity.

You can view other options with `rspec --help`.

Cheers!